# No CSS color preview icon in gutter in .css file in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, syntax-highlighting, gutter

I am using PyCharm as my IDE for about 1 year, and in my PyCharm setting --> Editor --> Appearance, "Show CSS color preview icon in gutter" is checked.

But the preview icon only shows in a `<style>` block in `.html`. And when I moved the styles into a separate `.css` file, the preview icon just not show.

How can I make the color preview icon show in a `.css` file in PyCharm ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't reproduce:

[image: CSS]

Check that `.css` is mapped to the correct file type in `Settings` | `File Types`.

Also try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` | `Invalidate and Restart`.

If the above doesn't help, [contact support](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home/) with a sample project to reproduce, your settings exported with `File` | `Export Settings` and [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446).

**UPDATE**: colors in the gutter may not show if you have `Highlighting Level` set lower than **Inspections**:

[image: level]

Comment: this was very helpful, tnx. Also note that this will not work if your power save mode in on!

Comment: Curiosity got the best of me here - I had turned on power saving mode and didn't notice my gutter color pickers missing until I forgot I had turned it off.  I hate you Power Save Mode - Go Away!!! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue (with PhpStorm) and the solution was to choose any other scheme than Dracula.

*Update*: Alternatively, I had to decrease the editor font size in order to display the colors. See [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151485).

Comment: The bug has been resolved as of the 2016.1.1 series of releases.

Answer (score 1):

Colors in the gutter also may not show if `Editor` => `General` => `Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl + Mouse Wheel` is on. Just turn it off or zoom out/in. If still nothing happened reopen the file.